# Laravel Personal Access Tokens

Tags: laravel, oauth-2.0, laravel-passport

Is there a way to re-view the accessToken itself after it's been created?

Looking at the code below you can see that $token holds the accessToken for the "Test Token" client and that's fine it works as expected, however, say the user forgot that $token is there a way to display it for the user again?

```
// user can manually create personal access token
// by using the following

$user = Auth::user();
$token = $user->createToken('Test Token')->accessToken;

// this works fine, however, I want to allow the user to edit / re-view these personal access
// tokens when he/she wants

// I'm able to delete or revoke these tokens but how can I vew the access token again?
// I tried the following:

foreach (Auth::user()->tokens as $token)
{
    // but none of these give back that access token??
    // halp!

    // print "accessToken: " . $token->accessToken;
    // print "token: " . $token->token;
}
```

Comment: any updates on this matter?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly: you can store the tokens in DB. If there is more tokens per user you can store it in json format.

Comment: So they have to be stored manually, there is no way to re-access them after the first time?